# How to add background image for application bar in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to add background image in application bar for my windows phone 7 application.
How to add background image for application bar in windows phone 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to load the image and use it as a background image for the main grid. then set the background opacity of the application bar so that you see the image.

the image needs to be formatted, of course, 480x800 but have what you want in the lower pixels where app bar usually is.